# History of square root of a matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, square-numbers, matrix-analysis

Im just curious, who invented the so called square root of a matrix? When it was started ?

I wonder why there is no any background of it in Wikipedia ?

Is it because finding a square root was just a corollary of past theorems, (for example, using Cayley-Hamilton.)?

Comment: The square root of a matrix is not exactly uniquely defined, maybe that's why.

Comment: Wikipedia is governed by the biases of its editors, none of whom answer to any central authority. This is as true of non-controversial topics like matrices as it is of controversial topics like Trump's dishonesty.

Comment: You're saying they didn't write a background section because they were biased about matrices? Maybe it didn't occur to them to write one.